# Ember render handlebar string with helper

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a helper which is meant to return different things like text, array in this case a button.

The important line is:

`return new Handlebars.SafeString('<button class="btn btn-default" {{action "'+col.btnAttr.action+'" '+col.btnAttr.actionContext+'}}>'+col.btnAttr.action+'</button>');`

but here my whole helper:

```
    import Ember from 'ember';

    export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(function(row,col,view){
      switch (col.type){
        case 'index':
          return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString('<span class="num">'+ view.contentIndex +'</span>');
        case 'text':
          return row.get(col.name);
        case 'array':
          var array = row.get(col.name);
          var string;
          array.forEach(function(item){
            string += ', ' + item;
          });
          return string;
        case 'button':
          return new Handlebars.SafeString('<button class="btn btn-default" {{action "'+col.btnAttr.action+'" '+col.btnAttr.actionContext+'}}>'+col.btnAttr.action+'</button>');

        default:
          return 'unknown type: ' + col.type;
      }
    });
```

The Problem is that I want to customize so many things and I'm not even knowing if it is a button when I call my helper

Comment: What don't you create more helpers?

Comment: @MateuszNowak Issued to the Idea of flexibility I would like to have one helper for in this case table cell content

Comment: What your question exactly?

Comment: @Microfed I need to return a String containing something like "{{action 'bla' }}" and doesn't want it to shown up as normal text, it needs to get recognized by handlebars..

Comment: did you ever get a solution for this?